# How to execute a for loop continously instead of getting stuck on a single repeating function?

Tags: lua, roblox

I'm trying to run a Function for all the Children of a model, but the function essentialy loops infinitely, preventing the next item in the `for` loop being called, I need either a better way of doing it or a workaround.

The main code:

```lua
local wave = workspace["Wave model"]
local move = require(script.Parent.moveModule)
local Players = game:GetService("Players")

Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function()
    for _, child in ipairs(wave:GetChildren()) do
        move.moveUp(child)
        wait(math.random(0.1,0.3))
        print("exec")
    end
    print("executed")
end)
```

The module I am calling:

```lua
local functions = {}

function functions.callNext(part, which)
    if which == "up" then
        functions.moveUp(part)
    else
        functions.moveDown(part)
    end
end

function functions.moveUp(part)
    local Tween = game:GetService("TweenService")

    local Objective = {}
    Objective.Position = Vector3.new(part.Position.X, part.Position.Y + 10, part.Position.Z)

    local tweenInfo = TweenInfo.new(5)

    local tweenie = Tween:Create(part, tweenInfo, Objective)

    print("played")
    tweenie:Play()
    print("done")
    tweenie.Completed:Connect(function()
        print("Fcuk")
    end)
    wait(5)
    functions.callNext(part, "down")
end

function functions.moveDown(part)
    local Tween = game:GetService("TweenService")

    local Objective = {}
    Objective.Position = Vector3.new(part.Position.X, part.Position.Y - 10, part.Position.Z)

    local tweenInfo = TweenInfo.new(5)

    local tweenie = Tween:Create(part, tweenInfo, Objective)

    print("played")
    tweenie:Play()
    print("done")
    wait(5)
    functions.callNext(part, "up")
end



return functions
```

Any ideas?

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff not sure that would let me go to the next item? My Tween will always last 5 seconds and that doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have an infinite loop, but rather a recursive loop: the functions in the module are calling each other until you will have a stack overflow. Spawning them in different threads will multiply that.

I would instead trigger your direction change by the tween's callback function, that way using asynchronicity:

```
local functions = {}

function functions.moveUp(part)
    local Tween = game:GetService("TweenService")

    local Objective = {}
    Objective.Position = Vector3.new(part.Position.X, part.Position.Y + 10, part.Position.Z)

    local tweenInfo = TweenInfo.new(5)

    local tweenie = Tween:Create(part, tweenInfo, Objective)
    tweenie:Play()
    tweenie.Completed:Connect(function()
        functions.moveDown(part)
    end)
end

function functions.moveDown(part)
    local Tween = game:GetService("TweenService")

    local Objective = {}
    Objective.Position = Vector3.new(part.Position.X, part.Position.Y - 10, part.Position.Z)

    local tweenInfo = TweenInfo.new(5)

    local tweenie = Tween:Create(part, tweenInfo, Objective)
    tweenie:Play()
    tweenie.Completed:Connect(function()
        functions.moveUp(part)
    end)
end

return functions
```

Btw -
You should read the docs on the tween service, its very neat. You can use it to go up and down in one run. That way you don't have to toggle with the two functions. Also you can smooth the movements with a sine wave.

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is edit the main script to run the moveup() function on a separate thread like so:

```
local wave = workspace["Wave model"]
local move = require(script.Parent.moveModule)
local Players = game:GetService("Players")

Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function()
    for _, child in ipairs(wave:GetChildren()) do
        spawn(function() move.moveUp(child) end) --Using an anonymous function as the spawn() function doesn't accept functions with parameters 
        wait(math.random(0.1,0.3))
        print("exec")
    end
    print("executed")
end)
```

This works, however in the long run you shouldn't do this as infinite loops running on multiple threads can cause significant lag if not optimised

**Code changed:**

```
move.moveUp(child)
```

to

```
spawn(function() move.moveUp(child) end)
```